# Format for action attribute in menu.xml

Tags: magento-2.0.7, magento2-migration-tool

Following the convention for value of the action attribute in menu.xml:

**[router_name]/[controller_name]/[action_name]**

I need to know how to give the value for my action attribute if my controller path is as:

**\app\code\Magenshop\Recipe\Controller\Adminhtml\Recipe\Edit.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magenshop\Recipe\Controller\Adminhtml\Recipe;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{


protected function _initAction()
{


    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('recipe/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(__('Items Manager'), __('Item Manager'));

    return $this;
}   

public function indexAction() {
    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
}

public function execute()
{

    //$this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
     $this->_view->loadLayout();
     $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
    $model  = $this->recipeRecipeFactory->create()->load($id); 

            /*Begin custom code */
    //Get the admin recipe approval status 
    $approveStatus=$model->getStatus(); 
    $this->generic->setApproveStatus($approveStatus);
            /*End custom code */
    $hlp = $this->recipeHelper;

    if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {
        /*Begin custom code */
        //getSingleton('adminhtml/session') changed to getSingleton('admin/session')
        $data = $this->backendAuthSession->getFormData(true);
        /*End custom code */
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        // $model->setFilename($hlp->getUploadHtml($model));
        $this->registry->register('recipe_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('recipe/items');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(__('Item Manager'), __('Item Manager'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(__('Item News'), __('Item News'));
        $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        $head->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
        $head->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
        // $head->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit_tabs'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    } else {
        $this->backendSession->addError(__('Item does not exist'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
     $this->_view->renderLayout();
}



/*public function editAction() {


 }*/
```

**app\code\Magenshop\Recipe\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml**

Is my action attribute value right here?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Magenshop_Recipe::menu" title="Recipes" module="Magenshop_Recipe" sortOrder="71" resource="Magenshop_Recipe::create"/>
    <add id="Magenshop_Recipe::menu_recipe" title="Manage Recipes" module="Magenshop_Recipe" sortOrder="1" parent="Magenshop_Recipe::menu" action="recipe/recipe/edit" resource="Magenshop_Recipe::menu_item"/>

</menu>
</config>
```

Comment: what you want actualy know?

Comment: I want to know the right way of specifying the path of my controller to my action attribute in menu.xml, right now if i click on the menu, its taking me to admin home page

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify path in `menu.xml` like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Magenshop_Recipe::menu" title="Recipes" module="Magenshop_Recipe" sortOrder="71" resource="Magenshop_Recipe::create"/>
    <add id="Magenshop_Recipe::menu_item" title="Manage Recipes" module="Magenshop_Recipe" sortOrder="1" parent="Magenshop_Recipe::menu" action="recipe/recipe/edit" resource="Magenshop_Recipe::menu_item"/>  <!--is this right? -->

</menu>
</config>
```

You need to move this file from here to

```
app\code\Magenshop\Recipe\Controller\Adminhtml\RecipeController.php
```

To

```
app\code\Magenshop\Recipe\Controller\Adminhtml\Recipe\Edit.php
```

And for another action, you need to create new file like this.

```
app\code\Magenshop\Recipe\Controller\Adminhtml\Recipe\Upload.php
```

Comment: I have updated my question, so in my controller if i have 5 actions, i should create seperate 5 files?   and also in the action attribute in menu.xml, no need to mention the 'adminhtml' in the path?

Comment: yes, Now in magento 2 you need to create seprate file for each action in extension with execute() method.

Comment: And if above answer help you, mark as solution so other get help in community as well.

Comment: Ok let me try this one, and one more thing, any change in the methods _initAction() and indexAction(), i suppose indexAction()  has to be changed to execute()  along with the respective action methods?  Like Edit.php should have execute() and edit(),   Upload.php should also have execute() and upload () action...

Comment: In magento 2, For every action you need to create one file and in file there is execute() method, is called when that action called.

Comment: I have updated the answer as suggested, whats wrong in my path still!, when i click on the link i get redirected to admin home page itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53679/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-sachin-s).